# Rename [bad-company] tags to [battlefield-bad-company]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

There are a few tags in the Battlefield: Bad Company series which could use renaming.

- [bad-company-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-company-2) -> [battlefield-bad-company-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlefield-bad-company-2)
- [bad-company-2-vietnam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-company-2-vietnam) -> [battlefield-bad-company-2-vietnam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlefield-bad-company-2-vietnam)
- [bad-company-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-company-series) -> [battlefield-bad-company-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlefield-bad-company-series)

Comment: Somehow I thought this was about EA lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done.** These have all been renamed:

- [bad-company-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-company-2) -> [battlefield-bad-company-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlefield-bad-company-2)
- [bad-company-2-vietnam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-company-2-vietnam) -> [battlefield-bad-company-2-vietnam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlefield-bad-company-2-vietnam)
- [bad-company-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bad-company-series) -> [battlefield-bad-company-series](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlefield-bad-company-series)